# Login to my own script using Disqus login

Tags: openid, disqus

Is it possible to use the Disqus login system to login to my website like it happens with Google, Facebook, Twitter, GitHub etc?

I'd like to let my users login to my website using Disqus accounts.

I can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Disqus offers a Single Sign-On (SSO) feature that can be enabled for your account. It allows a method for authenticating your site's users without requiring them to register for a global Disqus account. Your site must have its own database of users. More about SSO and how to integrate it on your site can be found here:

http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1104796-single-sign-on

Comment: I need the opposite thing, I need to let users to login with their own Disqus accounts in my own system.